# Is there a way for an OPC server to identify a client

Tags: com, atl, opc

I am facing a problem where I need to a identify whether an OPCAE client has previously connected to the OPCAE server (which I am writing). The reason I need this is to make sure the client doesn't miss any alarms while it was disconnected by caching alarms in the server and then as the client reconnects, do a Refresh with the missed alarms (if the previous subscriptions included those alarms). There is no such requirement in the OPC AE spec to catch alarms while disconnected.

In the previous version of the OPCAE server it made all subscription handles unique for a client, so client A would say use client handles 1-100 and client 2 would use 101-200 or something, this only works if the client is a custom one knowing what range they are allowed to use, connecting with say Matrikon OPC AE explorer could potentially reuse some of those handles.

Is there some standard way to handle this? When regarding the OPC there is the interface `IOPCCommon` with a method called `SetClientName` but that seems to be a more of an ad hoc way for a client to identify itself, if you start two OPC clients on the same PC they will get the same name (at least with Matrikon Explorer it seems so).

Clients can also connect remotely to the server via DCOM.

Is there maybe some way in the IConnectionPoint to identify a client that previously connected?

Comment: Since client handles are not unique, and probably cannot be, just play safe and don't fire past alarms.  If a client reconnects, it must update itself with no assumption of prior knowledge.  As for reconnections, it's not possible to identify a past client with `IConnectionPoint`, or rather with an object that doesn't implement an interface that clearly identifies the client other than by the identity of `IUnknown`.

Comment: @PauloMadeira thank you for your reply,I was suspecting something like that. IMHO it seems trying to solve this will result in some kind of hack.